# SSRS: separating totals and balances per client's account

Tags: reporting-services, expression

[Balances per client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOaNl.jpg)

I am creating a SSRS report where I have a page break per client's invoices etc. I'm looking for the expression for each of these boxes in the picture so that as a user pages through each supplier's accounts, the 'Balance Outstanding' and 'Net Purchases for Period' reflect the amounts separately for each client also; as opposed to overall balances and purchases.

Comment: What do you have for groups now? It looks like you need 2 more groups, by period and by client.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Thanks for your response. Yes, the report is a supplier enquiry by period. I have the periods sorted and the client side is dealt with through Dynamic CRM. When I'm looking for is the IIF(blah blah) part. The current expression is basic (=Sum(Fields!Total.Value, "dsPLTransactions"), I need to know how to have the total reflect the supplier's total separately.

Comment: Then you'll need to have Suppliers as a grouping as well. Then subtotal within each Client and Period.